# Routing with query params not working

Tags: angular

I want to route to this page passing a param: http://localhost:4200/inventory/client?id=2

What I do is:

```
this.router.navigate(['/inventory/client',{id:this.vendorId}]);
```

But result involves a semicolon: http://localhost:4200/inventory/client;id=2

What should i do to change it to: http://localhost:4200/inventory/client?id=2

Comment: As you can see by hovering over the time answered, I provided the answer first. It would be nice to reward the actual answer and not a copy. Glad to help anyway.

Comment: sorry i was not aware......

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 this.router.navigate(['/inventory/client'], { queryParams: { id: this.vendorId} });
```

And have a look here: [Passing Optional Parameters](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/query_params.html)

Comment: How do preserve queryParams when i have to come in via a url e.g. - _/#/SignUp/email=example@example.com&key=SomeExampleKey

Answer (score 1):

#### Make sure while passing query params value should not be undefined.

```
      this.router.navigate(['/inventory/client',
         queryParams : 
              {
                id : (this.vendorId ? this.vendorId : '')
              }
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **`queryParams`**

```
this.router.navigate(['/inventory/client'], { queryParams: { id: this.vendorId} });
```